# Re-rendering a react component after data is added to my firebase firestore back end database

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, addeventlistener

I have a react native component that displays a list of tasks based on how many there are in my firestore database. They are rendered initially upon the page rendering for the first time.

The user can add tasks and I would like the component on the screen to be re-ndered on the screen after new tasks are added/updated to the firestore database. Tasks are rendered from the tasks collection in my database.

Firesstore firebase structure:

```
users(collection)-->tasks(collection)-->taskdata(document)
```

Tasks are requested from the backend and set to the local state of the class component they are in.

```
constructor(props) {

        this.state = {

            tasks_: []
           
        }
}
```

Below a snapshot request of the database gets the tasks for the given user id and sets them to the local state.

```
getInfoHandler() {
        
          var docRefTest = 
            db.collection('users').doc(this.state.id).collection('tasks').get()
             .then(querySnapshot => {

              const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
              
              this.setState({ tasks_: documents });
        });
```

The component retrieves the tasks from the local state and renders them on the page. Mapping them per task stored in the back-end db.

Tasks are retrieved upon page render via component did mount calling on getInfoHandler() function.

I want a new  component to be rendered every time a task is added automatically.

```
export default class Tasks extends React.Component {

getInfoHandler() {

          var docRefTest = 
            db.collection('users').doc(this.state.id).collection('tasks').get()
             .then(querySnapshot => {

              const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

              this.setState({ tasks_: documents });
});

componentDidMount () {

   this.getInfoHandler();

}

render() {

        const tasks1 = this.state.tasks;

        return (
            <View style={styles.tasks}>
                        {tasks1.map((task) => {
                            return (
                                <TaskItem
                                    notes={task.notes}
                                    reminder={task.reminder}
                                    name={task.name}
                                    assigned={task.assigned}
                                
                                />
                            );
                        })}
                    </View>
                    
         )
     }
}
```

addTaskHandler() is used to add the tasks to the backend. It is located in a different modal component and activated upon button submit and closing the modal

```
addTaskHandler () {
 db.collection('users').doc(this.state.id).collection('tasks').doc().set({
            name: this.state.name,
            assigned: this.state.assigned,
            tag: this.state.tag
        })
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that adds new task ?

Comment: its in another Modal Component that pops up on the page I can edit the question and add it.

Comment: From what I understood, you want to locally render that new task after it is Firestore. So you can share that code as well?

Comment: yes the page is opened and tasks that already exist appear...but if the user adds a new one to the database I want it to appear on the page with out having to refresh the page manually.

Comment: I think i need to use snapshot() or componentDidUpdate() possibly?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: @imjared will onSnapshot() allow me to update the state? if the state is updated with onsnapshot() will this translate to the rendering of the page with new tasks added?

Comment: Can you just try `this.setState({ tasks_: [...existingTasks, {newTasksObject}] })` ? After doc is added to Firestore? Essentially added the new task object to existing documents?

Comment: what would {newTasksObject} consist of specifically? items retrieved from the snapshot?

Comment: The object that you are adding in Firestore document? `{name: this.state.name, assigned: this.state.assigned, tag: this.state.tag}` and maybe other fields that you have reminder and notes

Comment: so i need that in conjunction with onsnapshot?

Comment: No, if you are locally updating that new item you don't need onSnapshot. If you need to share these tasks to other devices then you should use onSnapshot and update state from there. (push the new item in tasks array)

Comment: is there to do this with an eventlistener type of action to where it recognizes when the store is updated...wont i still be telling it to look out for a newTaskObject and add it manually anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235454/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-matt-laszcz).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a combination of `useState`, `useEffect` and `onSnapshot()` (a listener).  Without giving ALL the details (partly because my code has layers of "wrapper" functions), it would like something like this for a functional component & hooks (HIGHLY HIGHLY HIGHLY recommended over Component Classes):

```
export default function ShowThese(props) {
  const {id} = props;

  const [tasks_, setTasks_] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(id)
      .collection('tasks')
      .onSnapshot(
        (querySnapshot) => {
        // returns a promise
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
          // DataFromSnapshot is what ever code you use to get an array of data from
          // a querySnapshot   
          let dataArray = DataFromSnapshot(querySnapshot);
          setTasks_(dataArray);
        } else //whatever you choose to do when there are no records;
      },
      (err) => {
        //whatever you want to do in case of an error
      }
    );
  }, [id]); //

  return //whatever you choose to render;
}
```

A couple notes:

`.onSnapshot` returns an unsubscribe *function*.  `useEffect()` will automatically call that function when your component unmounts - reduces memory leaks.  Kinda relies on the component unmounting/remounting if `id` changes.

every time the data from the query changes, the `(querySnapshot) =>{` function is called if successful (thus updating `tasks_`), and calling the `(err) =>{` function on error.

Comment: yes i was considering switching to a functional component for that very reason...to use useEffect and useState. I am going to do that and try what you recommended above!